# How to Upgrade Windows Mobile App to 7.1 Silverlight

Tags: silverlight

Exactly how the title reads,

Does anyone know how to upgrade a 7.0 application to a 7.1? I don't see an option for "Upgrade" or anything in my Solution Explorer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the tools for Windows Phone 7.5 first: http://create.msdn.com/en-us/home/getting_started

1. Right-click on the Phone project in the solution explorer
2. Select Properties
3. Select the Application Tab
4. In the Target Windows Phone OS drop down on the right, select Windows Phone OS 7.1.